# How to move between MVC controllers using knockout.js?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have an issue with moving from one MVC controller to another. I am new to MVC/Knockout combination and trying to find a best way.

I have a HomeController that does some login processes. The Login view, of the controller, contains knockout script that posts data it. After a certain select is chosen this code is executed by a button press with data-bind="clicked: SubmitLocation"

```
    self.SubmitLocation = function () {
        var jsonData = ko.toJSON(new LoginModel(self.Username, self.Password, self.isAuthenticated, self.UserId, self.SelectedLocId, self.SelectedLocDesc));
        alert(jsonData);
        $.ajax({
            ur: '@Url.Action("Login", "Home")',
            type: 'post',
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function () { }
        });
```

This brings it to the code inside MVC controller :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ....{
            return RedirectToAction("Products", "Product");
     ...}
```

Debugging through the code, I see that it makes it over to the Product controller and even to the Products view, without exceptions. However the page on the browser itself remains on the original HomeController/Login view. Where am I going wrong?

I have also tried returning a different view from the same HOmeController instead of RedirectToAction, and it is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `return RedirectToAction()` or `return View()` to an ajax call. Upon successful login, `return Json(true)` from the controller and in the `success` callback of ajax, redirect to the `Products` action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(UserViewModel user)
{
     // authentication code here

     return Json(true);
}
```

JS:

```
self.SubmitLocation = function() {
  var jsonData = ko.toJSON(new LoginModel(self.Username, self.Password, self.isAuthenticated, self.UserId, self.SelectedLocId, self.SelectedLocDesc));

  $.ajax({
    ur: '@Url.Action("Login", "Home")',
    type: 'post',
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
      if (data)
        location.href = '@Url.Action("Products", "Product")'; // redirect
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, as an additional quewstion, can I send a model with the redirect? Or is it possible to submit a form with some data from success jquery?

Comment: You can;t pass objects on url. You can only pass primitive datatypes in for example: `'@Url.Action("Products", "Product")?productId=' + productId` will redirect to `<yoursite>/Product/Products?productId=1` if productId is set 1

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also found that TempData works in this case as well.